# ThreeJS loadTexture collects images into memory and memory raises fast

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, three.js

If you open kemooolep.com/three with Chrome/windows, your browser will crash soon, beware! :)

Maybe someone have ideas how to change materials dynamically without having memoryleak

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve here.

First, your `onLoaded` function is called infinitely, even if it does not seem necessary.
This part, especially:

```
if (loadedCount == 6){
  onLoaded();
}
```

Then, I don't really understand why you want to call `THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture` only when the scene is ready ? It would be easier to load them directly, and assign them to `mesh.material.materials[index]` in their respective callbacks.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for anwser!
Currently this code is only for demo but what I want to achieve is that kind of qube where images are changing by time, let it be 2ms or 5000ms that does'nt matter. 

Problem is when new images are loaded then they will be never removed and memory usage raises and raises.

Comment: Then you have to manage a pool of %6 textures, and periodically load new ones.

Comment: That is what materials array does right now. Don't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have to dispose your unused texture. These will also remove the images